Noun vs pronoun
Are all numeral numbers (Cardinal, ordinal, mulplicative & decimal) Noun, pronoun or both?
Though we know that one is a pronoun. But what about others?

It depends how they're used in a sentence.

@StuartF For example?

You're the one who wants to know. What sentence are you interested in parsing?

See this, this, etc

You could always consult a dictionary though that's likely to be controversial. But certainly there's no reason to think "ten" is the same part of speech in "I gave the barman a ten" as in "I saw ten geese" or "He stayed in room ten".

Related: I'm 25 years old: would you consider "25" a noun or an adjective?.

Your questions are too short. You need to put more effort into composing your questions. You need to tell us what has led you to ask the question in terms of confusion over some theory or model, what you think the answer is and why, or why you question there even being a clear answer. It is unseemly to expect people to put more effort into answering than you have put into asking the question. What research did you do where, and what did you find? What are your own guesses and why?


Numbers
[1] Numbers such as one, five, eleven, two hundred, [3276] are cardinal
numbers.

We most commonly use cardinal numbers as determiners (before nouns).


When we use them in this way, we can use other determiners such as articles (a/an, the) and possessives (my, your) in front of them.




We can use cardinal numbers + of before determiners (one of my friends):



She loves animals and has two dogs, three cats and one rabbit.
My two best friends are Amy and Louise.
Three of his colleagues were sacked yesterday. (sacked = lost their
jobs)     Cambridge Dictionary

Most authorities (including CGEL) agree with this classification into the determiner(/determinative) word class. However, some grammarians regard cardinal numbers [being exact] in such usages as not being quantifiers (a subset of determiners), and some even demand a separate word class for numerals based on their different distributions. Certainly statements such as
6-2=4
I had six bullets and I have fired two. What have I left?
I am 37.
(with no mandatory head noun) have no obvious parallels.

[2] We also use cardinal numbers as nouns:
The children arrived in twos and threes.
[The 'three' has fallen of my
car number-plate.]
[You've miscopied a 'three' as a 'two'.] [op cit]

Wikipedia lists competing models:


Some theories of grammar use the word "numeral" to refer to cardinal numbers that act as a determiner that specify the quantity of a
noun, for example the "two" in "two hats".
Some theories of grammar do not include determiners as a part of speech and consider "two" in this example to be an adjective.
Some theories consider "numeral" to be a synonym for "number" and assign all numbers (including ordinal numbers like "first") to a part
of speech called "numerals".


[3] 'One' also exists as a genderless indefinite pronoun (and the corresponding noun).
One must learn to make economies.
He's such a one!

All cardinal numbers are nouns since they are things that make up the cardinal numbers (one, two, three, etc.). And all cardinal numbers can represent a group of things.
Example: "They ran home in groups of two."
However, only "one" can be used as a pronoun.
Example: "One can believe." This may refer to a specific individual, or many individuals.
Since cardinal numbers denote quantity, every cardinal number is also an adjective.

I think  numbers other than one can also function as pronouns. From KJV: "For where two or three are gathered together in my name, there am I in the midst of them."

@jejorda2 I'm not sure those are pronouns, I think it's just elision of "people": "For where two or three [people] are gathered..."

Two can live as cheaply as one.

@Barmar That's right: it's a determinative that appears as part of a determiner in a fused-head noun phrase.

@PaulTanenbaum Again, that's "two [people] can live as cheaply as one [person]".

Yes, @Barmar, I quite agree. But then most occurrences of one can be understood to mean “one [person].”

@PaulTanenbaum When we say "One can go to New York by train" it's being used as a pronoun to mean "anyone", not referring to a specific number of people.

Yes, @Barmar. Again, I agree.
